# When I open the rabbitmq container with the following command, the log inside the container is empty

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

When I use this command:

```
docker run -d --hostname rabbit1 --net=host --name myrabbit1 -p 4369:4369 -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='rabbitcookie' rabbitmq:3.6.9-management
```

The container is started but there is no log file. If I want to see the rabbit logs inside the container, how should I modify the above command?

Comment: which path did you check? Did you check `/var/log/rabbitmq`?

Comment: I went inside the container and looked at the logs in /var/log/rabbitmq/ and there was no content。   root@rabbit1:/# cd /var/log/rabbitmq/
root@rabbit1:/var/log/rabbitmq# ls
root@rabbit1:/var/log/rabbitmq#